# App crashes on clicking any button in the UI background while async task is running in the background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am fetching data from external server and populating it in a listview in android.During async task I show 'Loading' dialog in the UI thread.UI also shows two buttons in the background.On clicking these buttons ListAdapter is attached to listview and data is shown.
But since background thread is still running so the List Adapter is null and does not contain any data so on clicking these buttons app crashes showing null pointer excepton.
So how to make background UI(UI beneath 'Loading dialog') unresponsive while background thread is running? Or is there any other solution to it?

Comment: u need not do any ui related things on doinbackground post code...

Comment: @DIVA - I am not doing any UI related thing in doinbackground code.But if I click any button during doinbackground then app crashes because data is not fetched yet.

Comment: @DIVA - code is nearly 200 lines.

Comment: Don't put any button on progress dialog. Put the listadapter code in onpostexecute of your assynctask. So when the task gets completed it will dismiss dialogbox and populate your list.

Comment: put realted code of asyntask only

Comment: @AbhinavRaja don't put progress dialog at all. A simple spinner in the center of the empty list will be much better

Comment: My simple point is that how to make backgroud UI(buttons etc) while 'loading' dialog is being shown.Because If I click any button in between then app crashes because no data is fetched yet and that button allocates listadapter to listview

Comment: @AbhinavRaja - there is no button on dialog.But in the activity buttons are in the background(beneath dialog)

Comment: Or hide your buttons and make them visible in onpostexecute.

Comment: @AbhinavRaja - I have Put the listadapter code in onpostexecute of your assynctask.Things work fine if I wait for complete load but what if user clicks any button in the background in between.App will crash duw to null pinter exception

Comment: Are the buttons in your ui really required while the assync is running in background?  If not hide them or set clickabke to false untill task is completed.

Comment: What yur tryong to achieve is not possible.  App will crash if buttons are pressed during assync.  Just dissabke them during that time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop all interaction with the UI when running an AsyncTask, display a ProgressDialog and make it un-cancellable. Something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog mProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Show ProgressDialog
            mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            mProgress.setCancelable(false);
            mProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mProgress.setTitle("Fetching data");
            mProgress.show();
        }

        ...

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            // Hide ProgressDialog when done loading
            mProgress.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you UI will be unclickable while `doInBackground` is running.

Answer (score 0):

You definitively should add an Adapter to your ListView from the beginig event though it will be empty.
Then, when your AsyncTask is done, simply update the content of the Adapter.